# Android AsyncTask weird behavior

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a ListFragment that loads asynchronously multiple images but it behave in a strange way, [as you can see here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Nwlv_NvVSI).

Here's the AsyncTask code

```
public class BitmapWorkerClass extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap>
{
    private Context context;
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewWeakReference;
    private int data = 0;
    public BitmapWorkerClass(ImageView imageView, Context context)
    {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        imageViewWeakReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        data = params[0];
        return ImageResizer.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(context.getResources(),     data, 100,100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if(imageViewWeakReference != null && bitmap != null)
        {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewWeakReference.get();
            if(imageView != null)
            {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I call it from the ListFragment adapter's getView() method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment_single_recipe_title, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recipeTitleImage);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recipeTitleText);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Recipe recipe = getItem(position);
    loadBitmap(recipe.getImage(), holder.image);
    holder.title.setText(recipe.getTitle());
    return convertView;

public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView)
{
    BitmapWorkerClass task = new BitmapWorkerClass(imageView, getContext());
    task.execute(resId);
}
```

Can you help me to understand what makes the AsyncTask behave as in the video?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the fact is that there is not guarantee on how many times getView is called

Comment: but I need to update the UI into getView(), can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Post your recipe and entire adapter class code

Comment: try using holder.image.setImageBitmap(null); before calling loadBitmap method.

Comment: could you print how often getView() actually gets called ? I'd add the  hashCode for each convertView too, just to see if the same one gets called multiple times/recycled

Comment: it looks like your convertView gets recycled for whatever reason, this would cause multiple asynctasks to have a weak reference to the same imageview, which then all run their OnPostExecute in quick succession, causing this shuffle effect. Just a shot in the wild: do you add your adapter data in a loop and call notifyDataSetChanged() within the loop ? Possibly adding the data in reverse order ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably adding your data in a loop and calling notifyDataSetChanged() within the loop or you are using ArrayAdapters add() method. You possibly also add your data in a different order than displayed.

Therefore convertView gets recycled. This results in getView() for the same item to be called several times.

This causes multiple instances of BitmapWorkerClass to have a WeakReference to the same instance of ImageView. Each of them finish at some point and call OnPostExecute(), causing the shuffle effect.

Using a WeakReference (not recommended btw) helps with memory leaks, but it doesn't help you with View-recycling. The code below should fix the problem you have, however it might not be the most efficient way.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment_single_recipe_title, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recipeTitleImage);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recipeTitleText);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Recipe recipe = getItem(position);
        // cancel the previous asynctask if there was any
        if (holder.asynctask != null) {
            holder.asynctask.cancel(false);
            // you could pass true, but would have to handle the interruption then
        }
        // remove the previous image, you could set a default or loading image here instead 
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(null);
        holder.asynctask = loadBitmap(recipe.getImage(), holder.image);
        holder.title.setText(recipe.getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }

    public BitmapWorkerClass loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView)
    {
        BitmapWorkerClass task = new BitmapWorkerClass(imageView, getContext());
        task.execute(resId);
        return task;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        TextView title;
        BitmapWorkerClass asynctask; // save a reference to the asynctask
    }
```

Comment: that solved my issues, thank you a lot!

P.S.: Don't worry about the efficiency, this is a code from a sample app and I don't need it to be perfect ;-)

Comment: Good to hear. You can easily pull notifyDataSetChanged() out and place it after the loop. Or in case you are using ArrayAdapters add() method, switch to addAll() instead. If you add the code to your question i can tell you more.